# adding unique styles to data filtering attributes

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm doing some `img` filtering using HTML5 data attribute (eg:) I'm wondering the best method to apply custom styles to appear if say `data-rel="anim"` was **selected**? What is the best way to target '`data-filter='anim`' and `data-rel="anim"` so that when these thumbs are populated via selecting the button, they will have larger dimensions and slightly different placement then the other default thumb styles.

```
  <a data-rel="all" href="javascript:;" class="filter active">View all</a>
  <a data-rel="anim" href="javascript:;" class="filter three">3 Columns</a>
  <a data-rel="land" href="javascript:;" class="filter four">4 Columns</a>

<div class="galleryWrap cf">
<a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='./gallery/dress.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='arch'><img src='./gallery/dress.jpg' alt='image ./gallery/dress.jpg' /></a>
<a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='./gallery/dress.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='./gallery/dress.jpg' alt='image ./gallery/dress.jpg' /></a>
<a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='./gallery/dress.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='./gallery/dress.jpg' alt='image ./gallery/dress.jpg' /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you can use the data attribute in a selector. You can then apply a class with the styles you want.

```
$("a[data-rel='anim']").on('click', function() {
  $("a[data-filter='anim']").addClass('selectedStyles');
});
```